# Windows XP: Add a program to the list of programs that can be mapped to open a filetype

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-2, file-types

I have a filetype (.xyz) that I would like to map to a text editor (sublime).  It is currently mapped to open with notepad.

Attempts to map .xyz filetype:

1) Open file explorer, select .xyz file and right click: select properties

2) Click Change button

3) Browse-to and select target .exe

[image]

I could not add the target text editor .exe (sublime) to the list of programs circled in red, nor could I associate it with the target filetype.  Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have local admin rights?

Comment: Good question: yes, 'computer administrator' privileges